# How to return array to new Map ? using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to return back from array to new Map data.

I have a array:

```
let test = [
['test' , true],
['test1' , true],
['test2' , true]
];
```

I need to set this to new Map like a :

```
{ 'test' => true }
{ 'test1' => true }
{ 'test2' => true }
```

What i am try ?

```
newMapData = [...new Map(test)];
```

But this is no work correctly.

I am using : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_maps.asp

Comment: Just `newMapData = new Map(test)`?

Comment: Use the [official documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead. In particular, see what [parameters the `Map` constructor](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map#parameters) accepts.

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to spread the map. `newMapData = new Map(test)` works perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to the new ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) simply do it without  [...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
let test = [
  ['test', true],
  ['test1', true],
  ['test2', true]
];
const newMapData = new Map(test);
// Unfortunately Maps don't show well with console.log:
for (let [key, value] of newMapData) {
  console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
// Map {"test" => true, "test1" => true, "test2" => true}
```